# Generate sample process with CrossSectional Correlation and autoregressive structure

Tags: random-generation, autoregressive, covariance-matrix

How can you generate a sample multidimensional time series $X_{t,i}$ for $t \in \{1,2,...,T\}$ and $i \in \{1,2,...,M\}$ where:

1. $E[X_{t,i}] = 0$
2. $E[X_{t,i}X_{t,j}] = \Sigma_{i,j}$
3. $E[X_{t,i}|X_{t-1,i}] = a_i X_{t-1,i}$

I can generate a process with properties 1 and 2 or 1 and 3 but I'm not sure how to generate a process with all 3 properties.

Right now I am thinking about re-stacking the matrix into a giant vector and trying to generate this process but this seems really computationally inefficient.

What else can I try?

Comment: You would need to derive the full distribution ${\bf X}_t | {\bf X}_{t-1}$. This would only require the $2M \times 2M$ block matrix $\begin{pmatrix}\Sigma & {\rm diag}({\bf a}) \\ {\rm diag}({\bf a}) & \Sigma\end{pmatrix}$, and then you can apply the standard (multivariate normal) conditioning rules. You may stumble upon non-existence, though: if $a_1=0.9$ and $a_2=-0.9$, then they pull $X_{t,1}$ and $X_{t,2}$ in different directions, so the second constraint may be tough to satisfy.